# Can Custom App Store Listings be created?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I want my app to show different metadata (title, subtitle, description, images etc) for different countries.

The way of doing this in Google Play Store would be to create custom listings.

Is the same possible for App Store? If not, what are the ways of doing this? How international Apps like booking.com, uber etc do it?

I have gone through this documentation: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev34e9bbb5a and the only thing that stands out is have different apps for different territories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different app store pages by adding additional languages to your app on App Store Connect.

[image]

Simply go to App Store Connect > My Apps > Choose the app > Click on the languages dropdown on the right and add the languages. Then click on the version below "IOS APP" and you can add your language specific information.

That's exactly the same why as you would do it on Google Play Dev Console. Custom listing are something completely different as they allow you to target more specific audiences. The general languages correspond with the user language / store front.

Comment: How do I separate this for US and for India, where the language for both would be English (US). I want separate metadata for both the countries.

Comment: It's not possible to do that on App Store Connect. You can only localize by language and there is currently no way to select English (India) as you can select English (UK) or English (Australia).

Comment: Thanks! I have decided to update the metadata at a global level while balancing the content to make it relevant for all audiences :)